# unable to Read the config file data from local drive

Tags: c#, configuration, config, filepath

I fail to read the appSettings from a config file. It is not located in the default location so when I tried using `var aWSAccessKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AWSAccessKey"];` it didn't work.

Config file:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="AWSAccessKey" value="1" />
    <add key="AWSSecretKey" value="2" />
    <add key="AWSRegion" value="4" />
    <add key="AWSAccountNumber" value="5" />
</appSettings>
```

Also tried with no success:

```
var fileMap = new ConfigurationFileMap("D:AWS\\CoreLocalSettings.config");
var configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedMachineConfiguration(fileMap);
var sectionGroup = configuration.GetSectionGroup("applicationSettings");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally it's working:

In the `app.config` file I read the outside config file data as below

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings file="D:\AWS\CoreLocalSettings.config">
    .......
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

In the code base I am accessing same using the `ConfigurationManager`

```
var strAWSAccessKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AWSAccessKey"];
```

Comment: cleaner solution. Can you attach where you found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
    var web = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager
      .OpenWebConfiguration(@"D:\Employee\Hitesh\Projects\Web.config");

    var appValue = web.AppSettings.Settings["SMTPServerPort"].Value;
```

Comment: Code-only answers are generally not liked here, please consider adding some explanation.

Answer (score -1):

```
    var AWSAccessKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AWSAccessKey"];
```

Comment: config file is not in the project hierarchy its outside some where in the local drive with the above content I need to read the app settings.

the above solution I tried already it's will not work.

Comment: reference  using System.Configuration;